# How to pass complete Webcontrol?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to pass a complete Webcontrol to a method with reference that will set value of that webcontrol by determining its type.

```
enter code here
public void SetValue(ref WebControl,string value){
       Type t=WebControl.Gettype();

       if(t.Name== "TextBox"){
          // set TextBox Value
       }
      else if (t.Name=="Dropdown"){
      // set Dropdown value.
  }
```

}

//////////////Calling of above function in aspx.cs file.

```
SetValue(ref txEmployee,"123");
```

I am using asp.net Webforms.

Answer (score 0):

Box control into object and work with object itself.

```
//Method
public void SetValue(ref object oWebControl,string value){
       switch (oWebControl.GetType().Name)
        {
            case "RadioButton": { /*do stuff here*/} break;
            case "DropDownList": { /*do stuff here*/} break;
            case "TextBox": { /*do here*/} break;
            /*more checking here*/
            default: break;
        }
  }

//Box the control (Boxing)
//For RadioButton
object o = RadioButton as object;
//For DropDownList
object o = DropDownList as object;
//For TextBox
object o = TextBox as object;
/*more control here*/

//Call Method
SetValue(ref o,"123");
```

I hope this is something you are looking for.